# can firebug be accessed through visual studio

Tags: firebug

All I need to know, is if it is possible to access firebug panels from visual studio?

Comment: I'm just really curious... Why do you need that? If you want to improve it or customize you can just edit the addon itself...

Comment: I find that some pages that are difficult to parse, often the content is visible / and extractable when using firebug. This would be very helpful if I can have an app access the content returned in firebug and automatically extract it.This is not about firebug but content of certain web pages...ie screens scraping
Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer - No.

But you might want to detail what kind of access you're talking about.

Comment: as above...screen scraping results that ordinarily I cannot obtain through source page or fetching the url through webrequest.

Comment: is there any way to obtain the response body content from firebug programmatically? Hope I am a little more clear now with my intentions.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, to some extent.  Take a look at this: [How do I debug JavaScript in Visual Studio 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398/how-do-i-debug-javascript-in-visual-studio-2005)